# Как обнулить внутренние отступы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Возможно ли обнулить внутренние отступы у различных тегов?
Допустим имеем тег `h1`, видно, что при больших размерах текста есть верхний и нижний отступ.
Текст не прижат к краям блока по вертикали.
Можно ли это исправить?

```css
h1 {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: Кажется поможет установить `margin: 0` у `body`. А лучше использовать [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). И ещё вместо `-webkit-margin-...` лучше использовать просто `margin`/`margin-top`/`margin-bottom`/`margin-left`/`margin-right`.

Comment: Причем здесь margin? Регулируйте через line-height, как вам подсказали

Comment: @DaemonHK,   а ` line-height`  тут каким боком???

Comment: @Air регулирование высоты строки же

Comment: @DaemonHK, все верно, но без высоты фиксированной грощ ей цена

Comment: @Air высота для кого? для текста? бред

Comment: @DaemonHK, точно бред))))))  Меня сбило с толку одна статья, давно ее читал...  Ты прав....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `line-height`:

```css
h1 {
  background: red;
  line-height: .7; 
}
```

```html
<h1>
hello
</h1>
```

Но не забудьте что отступы там оставлены специально для выносных элементов, например:

```css
h1{
   background: red;
}

h1.gool{ 
  line-height: .7; 
}

sub,sup{
  line-height: 0
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gool">
hel<sup>2</sup>o go<sub>2</sub>l
</h1>

<h1>
hel<sup>2</sup>o go<sub>2</sub>l
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Задать свойство `line-height`.

```css
h1 {
  background: red;
  line-height: .7;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: Уберите `height`, то же самое получите

Comment: @DaemonHK, как видишь убрал)))))